# Include_Path, require once, PHP issues using Zend

Tags: php, zend-framework, include-path, require-once

I am new to PHP, so I apologize for my inexperience.  I am working in a Windows 10 environment and have installed WAMP to serve Apache, PHP, and MySQL.  I am creating some remoteObject webservices for an Adobe AIR app that will communicate with Zend using AMF, and I have created an index.php file to get everything in motion, but when I browse to the index.php file, I get all kinds of errors.  Here is the index.php file:

**index.php**

```
<?php
   require_once('Zend/Amf/Server.php');
   require_once('HalfService.php');

   $server = new Zend_Amf_Server();
   //adding our class to Zend AMF Server
   $server->setClass("HalfService");
   //Mapping the ActionScript VO to the PHP VO
   //you don't have to add the package name
   $server->setClassMap("VOService", "VOService");
   echo($server -> handle());
?>
```

My File structure is:

```
C:/wamp64/www/
              ZendFramework/library/Zend/Amf/Server.php
              zendamf_remote/index.php
                             HalfService.php
                             VOService.php
```

I tried to create a include_path in my php.ini file that looks like this, but it did not work:

```
include_path = “c:\wamp64\www\ZendFramework\library”
```

Finally, this is the error that I get when I browse to index.php in a browser:

```
( ! ) Warning: require_once(Zend/Amf/Server.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\wamp64\www\zendamf_remote\index.php on line 2

( ! ) Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required 'Zend/Amf/Server.php' (include_path='�c:\wamp64\www\ZendFramework\library�') in C:\wamp64\www\zendamf_remote\index.php on line 2
```

Any help at all in getting this configured would really be appreciated.  Thanks so much!

Comment: You probably need the Zend autoloader as well. Are you ale to do this with composer instead?

Comment: Have you tried include_path = “c:/wamp64/www/ZendFramework/library”

Comment: Have you tried forward-slashes in your include path. The back-slashes may be being treated as escape characters

Comment: Does `c:\wamp64\www\ZendFramework\library\Zend\Amf\Server.php` exist? That is what PHP is failing to load.

Comment: @sashi , I did try forward slashes in the include_path name, it did not help.  I initially put in back slashes because the php.ini file has Windows examples commented out that use backslashes, but in the end, either way did not make a difference.  Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: @Tim Fountain, I have checked to be absolutely certain and the file does exist. One thing that bothers me is the strange symbols in the error message, they look like diamonds with question marks in them around the include_path inside the error message.  I don't know why they are there, and it concerns me that I have entered the include_path incorrectly??

Comment: In your question you appear to have smart quotes around the path, so that may be it. See if changing that helps.

Comment: @Tim Fountain.  You are the man!!  I really appreciate your help.  I wouldn't have spotted that in a bazillion years.  I didn't even know there were different types of quotes.  I actually just copied the path right out of Explorer on Windows and pasted it in.  Ugggh, that was frustrating.  I would like to give you credit for answering my question.  Is there a way to do that from comments??  Or could you actually post a response and I could mark it as solved??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"In your question you appear to have smart quotes around the path, so that may be it. See if changing that helps. – Tim Fountain"

Thanks to Tim Fountain for answering this question, who noticed something I wouldn't have seen in a million years